# unable to select listbox item through data template in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I am unable to select desired item from the listbox
(when i click on any item in that listbox  the items more than one are getting selected but not the one on which i have clicked). Also the background color of the selected items are getting changed to default (white) color.
The Xaml code used by me is as follows:

```
<ListBox x:Uid="lst_value" Name="lstValues" Background="Wheat"
    BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
    BorderThickness="1" Height="100" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding listval}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Wheat">
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtblk" Foreground="Black" FontSize="10"
                    TextAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Black" Text="{Binding}"
                    Background="Wheat"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Could anyone let me know how to resolve the issue please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not set the `Background` on the `StackPanel` and `TextBlock`, that obfuscates the selection. To override the background for the selection add resources to your ListBoxItems.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Style.Resources>
            <!-- Selected Brush -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green" />
            <!-- Selected but out of focus Brush -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="LightGreen" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <!-- If you must set a Background, do it here, should be superfluous though as the ListBox.Background is the same -->
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Wheat" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

The selection issue can appear if you have a source collection with identical objects (like strings that have the same value).

Comment: thanks a lot, i could resolve it..., I kept inserting identical strings in to the list collection..for testing purpose..now if i enter distinct strings..its working..Thank you.

Comment: Someone else did the exact same thing yesterday :)

Comment: oh!!..now i could not select multiple items...from the listbox..could you please tell me why is that so...!!

Comment: @somasekhar: Just change the [`ListBox.SelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectionmode.aspx) (to `Multiple` for example, the default is `Single`)

Comment: that's Cool..I made it extended, now I could select either single item or multiple one's..I got it...great.Thank you..:-)

Comment: could you please let me know, how to set the border property with corner radius=5 in the style in the above listbox...

Comment: @somasekhar: Just make the border part of your ItemTemplate. Also set the content alignments in the style to stretch, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188371/fill-grid-width-inside-a-listbox/6188604) for reference.

Comment: @somasekhar: You cannot accept more than one answer by the way, so if you are going to go with HCL's you could at least upvote mine if you have not already. (I'd also suggest you upvote answers you accept, as they normally are not only correct but also helpful, also try not to change the accepts so often, it's annoying people)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3094/discussion-between-soma-sekhar-and-h-b)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem right, then the selection logic of the listbox reacts weird. Right?

In most cases, such behaviour has to do with the Equals() or/and the GetHashCode() method of your items (the objects in your `listVal` enumeration). Make sure you have not multiple objects in your list that return true for a call to Equals() of one object. Make also sure, you have not objects that return changing values for GetHashCode() (some random values).

If you found the problem in the above methods (I assume Equals) but you must say that you can not change the implementation of Equals(), consider creating a wrapper object for your items (a ViewModel).

Comment: @soma sekhar: If you have equal objects in your listVal enumeration, the selection logic has a problem which item to select. Equality is checked by the Equals()-Method. Therefore make sure that you have not multiple objects in your list that are equal compared by the equal-method. E.g. if you insert two identical strings or two identical integer values, the selection will react weird.

Comment: thanks a lot, i could resolve it..., you were right, i kept inserting identical strings in to the list collection..for testing purpose..now if i enter distinct strings..its working..Thank you.

Comment: oh!!..now i could not select multiple items...from the listbox..could you please tell me why is that so...!!:-(

Comment: @soma sekhar: Have you set SelectionMode = System.Windows.Controls.SelectionMode.Multiple?

Comment: yap..i have made it extended...now i could select either single item or multiple items..thank you..:-)

Comment: could you please let me know, how to set the border property with corner radius=5 in the style in the above listbox...

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong listval is a `List<string>` or any other list of primitive types..
Reason why it is behaving wired with your case is primitive types are struct not classes.

instead of using  list of primitive types try using concrete class's

Lets say it you are using List of names like List..

Create a class having name property

```
class person
{
public string Name{get;set;} 
}
```

use List and you can bind the name property

Comment: I have implemented it the same way..where "listval" is the get property retrieved through "observablecollection<>" class....

Comment: if it is a observablecollection<>" class then how come your textblock was binded directly (Text="{Binding}")... why it was not binded to any property..? is it possible to publish a part to your viewmodel which will help us to give better answers

Comment: i could resolve it..i was inserting the identical strings in to the list collection..now, i tried with distinct strings, with which i could select the items properly..

Comment: if you are sure that you will not get any identical strings in that list in future then you can consider this as fix otherwise consider using List concrete class in the place of strings. Because all primitive types are struct's (in your case strings)..

Comment: Thank you for that...however, when List<> class is used I was unable to bind the items to the listbox at all..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was wrongly adding **ComboBoxItems** to the ListBox.Items collection. Adding objects other than a "**ListBoxItem**" to the Items collection caused this behavior for me.