# List Box Item template layout

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

I have listbox which will show the list of text and its status. How shall i show the text in the left side and Status control on the right most side?
This is how i was trying.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <DockPanel>
             <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTitle}"/>
            <ContentControl DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="{Binding Status}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource StatusTemplate}" />                              
         </DockPanel>                       
    </DataTemplate>
```

This code is showing the status control just after the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would use a [`Grid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx) with two columns:

1. `*` sized
2. `Auto` sized (or set a [`SharedSizeGroup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want synchronization between items)

The first column will take up all space left. For size sharing you will also need to set [`Grid.IsSharedSizeScope`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on e.g. the `ListBox` element.

The items also [need to be stretched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188371/fill-grid-width-inside-a-listbox/6188604#6188604).

Comment: Applied the solution but still it is the same for the list box items. Is there any reason this happens for the items in list box?. because i could see the treeview items are aligned correctly

Comment: Right, set `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch` on the `ListBox`.